# Invocation target exception on Java applet

Tags: java, html, exception, applet, awt

I'm finishing up a project for my first java class, and I'm creating an 
applet to be embedded into HTML. I'm getting an Invocation target exception and I can't
figure it out. All of my classes are in the same dir along with the HTML file and the jar file. They're all in a file where I save all of my java projects, if the location has anything to do with it.

It's a program with two sub classes which are event listeners for buttons in the main 
class. It's meant to count votes with the listeners, and It runs normally, but not as an HTML applet. I don't think the code of the program is going to be the issue, but here it is:

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;

 public class votes {

     static int A;
     static int B;
     static TextField yescount;
     static TextField nocount;

     public static void main(String[] args) {

         yeslistener yus = new yeslistener();
         nolistener nos = new nolistener();
         A = 0;
         B = 0;
         Frame frame = new Frame("Votes");
         frame.setSize(600, 600);
         frame.setVisible(true);

         Label label = new Label("Is java a fun programming language?");
         label.setBounds(50, 50, 400, 50);
         frame.add(label);

         nocount = new TextField("0");
         nocount.setBounds(450, 400, 100, 50);
         nocount.setForeground(Color.red);
         frame.add(nocount);

         yescount = new TextField("0");
         yescount.setBounds(50, 400, 100, 50);
         yescount.setForeground(Color.green);
         frame.add(yescount);

         Button yes = new Button("Yes");
         yes.setBounds(50, 500, 100, 50);
         yes.addMouseListener(yus);
         frame.add(yes);

         Button no = new Button("No");
         no.setBounds(450, 500, 100, 50);
         no.addMouseListener(nos);
         frame.add(no);

         Label lbl = new Label();
         frame.add(lbl);
     }

     static class yeslistener extends MouseAdapter {

         public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {

             A++;
             yescount.setText(A + " Votes");
         }
     }

     static class nolistener extends MouseAdapter {

         public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {

             B++;
             nocount.setText(B + " Votes");
         }
     }
 }
```

I packed all three classes into a jar file to be used as the archive.
Here is my HTML file that I use to call the class and archive jar file:

```
<HTML>
<Head> <title> Votes </title> </head>
<body>
<applet Code= "votes.class"
 archive= "votes.jar"
 width="600" height="600">
</applet>
</body>
</HTML>
```

And my exception from the Java console looks like this:

```
basic: exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.runOnEDTAndWait(Unknown     Source)
at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.instantiateApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.OldPluginAWTUtil.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: votes cannot be cast to java.applet.Applet
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
basic: Removed progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@17c9937
```

I've been searching for answers for a while now, and I feel like the Exception doesn't give me enough information to be able to sort it all out. Any help that you could give me would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: *"I'm finishing up a project for my first java class, and I'm creating an applet"*  (alarm bells) See [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/) for the reasons why I think it is ambitious to be making an applet until later, after you have made a couple of (`JFrame` based) applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applets don't use a main method to execute. Applets are subclasses of `java.applet.Applet` and are AWT Panels, rendered just like a `java.awt.Panel`. Applets are started with their `init()` and `start()` methods.

See [The Official Java Tutorials' article on Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/) to learn how to use applets.

Comment: I changed my main() to a start() and it ended up working. Thanks a ton for the help